# What does "scare you" mean?

Tags: vocabulary

I understand some about "scare" like I'm scared of the dark.
However, I heard this word and I'm not sure it is "scare you" or scared you".
Could you tell me what it means?

Comment: Both are equally likely.  We need more context.

Comment: I heard it from a cartoon. An accident happened and a cartoon car said that "scared you or scare you" to another car that had an accident. It sounded like a question like this “Scared you or Scare you?” I wonder whether it means "Are you scared?" or not.

Answer (score 3):

**Present Tense**

`scare you`: The people at the haunted house will scare you.

**Past Tense**

`scared you`: The people at the haunted house have already scared you.